# How to deploy different MERN apps to digital ocean on a single droplet?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, digital-ocean, mern

I've always used heroku to deploy my MERN apps. For the mongo db I use MongoDB Atlas, but in my job they want to migrate all the projects to DigitalOcean. I have several questions regarding this:

1. Can I have mongoDB + nodejs backend + react app on a single
   droplet?
2. Can I deploy two or more apps in a single droplet? (The
   apps have different domains)
3. Is there a video tutorial about this
   (I've read lots of documentations and got many errors while trying
   to do it. My eyes hurt )
4. For example if I have in Heroku two apps for the same website, one app for the nodejs backend and another one for the react frontend... can I do the same on DigitalOcean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yeah, you can deploy multiple services in a single server, they just need to be listening on different ports.**

For example, let's consider that a MongoDB server is running on port `27017`, a Node.js http server is running on port `5000`, and a React app is running on port `8000`.

Say, your server's IP is `13.13.13.13`.

Then you can access your MongoDB server, Node.js http server, and React app using `13.13.13.13:27017`, `13.13.13.13:5000`, and `13.13.13.13:8000`, respectively, from anywhere in the Internet where your IP isn't blocked.

Now, in your server, you set up `iptables` to forward all incoming connections from port `8000` to `80`. Now, you can access your React app by visiting `13.13.13.13`, no need to use the port anymore.

Now, let's say, you add DNS records for `example.com` and `api.example.com` to point to your IP. And since you can't have `A` records or `CNAME` records pointing to a port, both of your domains will direct you to your React app. You'll have to explicitly specify the port number along with your domain if you want to access your Node.js backend, like `http://example.com:5000`, or `http://api.example.com:5000`.

If you don't want to access your backend using the port number, you can make use of Nginx as a reverse proxy. You can set up Nginx to route all the traffic to `api.example.com` to your backend server listening on `localhost:5000`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this is confusing. (Say my ip is 13.13.13.13) Where exactly do I put 13.13.13.13:5000 and 13.13.13.13:27017? I don't understand what's happening in the 'default' file and what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: @renoldus, do you have a MERN/MEAN app, because it looks like you are not familiar with the M and the N.